# get the secleted lable text based on the value of select option

Tags: jquery, select

Here is my Select Options Code,
How can i read the text of selected option lable. both are coming in two separate div's

```
<div id="eligiblebranch_checklist" style="position: relative; height: 92.2333px; width: 359.35px;" class="checklist">
    <ul class="checklist">
        <li tabindex="0" class="even"><input value="1" name="eligiblebranch[]" id="eligiblebranch_1" type="checkbox"><label for="eligiblebranch_1" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox"> Computer Science Engineering </label></li>
        <li tabindex="0" class="odd"><input value="2" name="eligiblebranch[]" id="eligiblebranch_2" type="checkbox"><label for="eligiblebranch_2" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox"> Chemical Engineering </label></li>
        <li tabindex="0" class="even"><input value="3" name="eligiblebranch[]" id="eligiblebranch_3" type="checkbox"><label for="eligiblebranch_3" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox"> Civil Engineering </label></li>
        <li tabindex="0" class="odd"><input value="4" name="eligiblebranch[]" id="eligiblebranch_4" type="checkbox"><label for="eligiblebranch_4" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox"> Electrical Engineering </label></li>
        <li tabindex="0" class="even"><input value="5" name="eligiblebranch[]" id="eligiblebranch_5" type="checkbox"><label for="eligiblebranch_5" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox"> Electronics &amp; Communication Engineering </label></li>
        <li tabindex="0" class="odd"><input value="6" name="eligiblebranch[]" id="eligiblebranch_6" type="checkbox"><label for="eligiblebranch_6" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox"> Mechanical Engineering </label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you try to expound on your question to clarify what you want, what you have tried, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map`, `get` and `join` will do the trick.

```
var selected = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(){
      return $(this).next('label').text();
}).get().join(",");
```

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  var selected = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(){
      return $(this).next('label').text();
  }).get().join(",");
  console.log(selected);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="eligiblebranch_checklist" style="position: relative; height: 92.2333px; width: 359.35px;" class="checklist">
    <ul class="checklist">
        <li tabindex="0" class="even"><input value="1" name="eligiblebranch[]" id="eligiblebranch_1" type="checkbox"><label for="eligiblebranch_1" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox"> Computer Science Engineering </label></li>
        <li tabindex="0" class="odd"><input value="2" name="eligiblebranch[]" id="eligiblebranch_2" type="checkbox"><label for="eligiblebranch_2" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox"> Chemical Engineering </label></li>
        <li tabindex="0" class="even"><input value="3" name="eligiblebranch[]" id="eligiblebranch_3" type="checkbox"><label for="eligiblebranch_3" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox"> Civil Engineering </label></li>
        <li tabindex="0" class="odd"><input value="4" name="eligiblebranch[]" id="eligiblebranch_4" type="checkbox"><label for="eligiblebranch_4" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox"> Electrical Engineering </label></li>
        <li tabindex="0" class="even"><input value="5" name="eligiblebranch[]" id="eligiblebranch_5" type="checkbox"><label for="eligiblebranch_5" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox"> Electronics &amp; Communication Engineering </label></li>
        <li tabindex="0" class="odd"><input value="6" name="eligiblebranch[]" id="eligiblebranch_6" type="checkbox"><label for="eligiblebranch_6" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox"> Mechanical Engineering </label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<button>Get selected</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for Solutions

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what you exactly want, but I give it a try with:

```
var labelText = $(".checklist :checkbox:checked").siblings("label").text();
```

Comment: You need a space after `.checklist`, since the checkbox is a child.

Comment: And it should be `.text()`. Labels don't have a value.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $("input[type=checkbox]").on("change",function(){
        
         var text = "";
        
        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
            
              text += $(this).next().text() + " ";
            
          });
         
          console.log(text);
         
    })
     
})
```

```html
<div id="eligiblebranch_checklist" style="position: relative; height: 92.2333px; width: 359.35px;" class="checklist">
    <ul class="checklist">
        <li tabindex="0" class="even"><input value="1" name="eligiblebranch[]" id="eligiblebranch_1" type="checkbox"><label for="eligiblebranch_1" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox"> Computer Science Engineering </label></li>
        <li tabindex="0" class="odd"><input value="2" name="eligiblebranch[]" id="eligiblebranch_2" type="checkbox"><label for="eligiblebranch_2" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox"> Chemical Engineering </label></li>
        <li tabindex="0" class="even"><input value="3" name="eligiblebranch[]" id="eligiblebranch_3" type="checkbox"><label for="eligiblebranch_3" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox"> Civil Engineering </label></li>
        <li tabindex="0" class="odd"><input value="4" name="eligiblebranch[]" id="eligiblebranch_4" type="checkbox"><label for="eligiblebranch_4" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox"> Electrical Engineering </label></li>
        <li tabindex="0" class="even"><input value="5" name="eligiblebranch[]" id="eligiblebranch_5" type="checkbox"><label for="eligiblebranch_5" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox"> Electronics &amp; Communication Engineering </label></li>
        <li tabindex="0" class="odd"><input value="6" name="eligiblebranch[]" id="eligiblebranch_6" type="checkbox"><label for="eligiblebranch_6" class="leaveRoomForCheckbox"> Mechanical Engineering </label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```